# Style scrollbar slider

Tags: css

How to style the scrollbar of a slider that you see horizontally at the bottom? It is a big question and I have not solution. What am I missing? I have to put more text here why?

```css
.slider {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: flex;
 overflow-x: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
  &:-webkit-scrollbar {
   color: red;
   background-color: green;
  }
  &:-scrollbar-button {
   color: blue;
   background-color: yelow;
  }
}

.img {
 flex-shrink: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
<div class="img" id="img"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/200/300"></div>
<div class="img" id="img1"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/g/200/300"></div>
<div class="img" id="img2"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/300"></div>
<div class="img" id="img3"><img src="http://stevensegallery.com/200/300"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everyone hates styled scrollbars. Reconsider doing it.

Comment: I think it's personal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How TO - Custom Scrollbar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)

```css
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px blue; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: yellow; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: green; 
}

.slider {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: flex;
 overflow-x: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }

.img {
 flex-shrink: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
<div class="img" id="img"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/200/300"></div>
<div class="img" id="img1"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/g/200/300"></div>
<div class="img" id="img2"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/300"></div>
<div class="img" id="img3"><img src="http://stevensegallery.com/200/300"></div>
</div>
```

[use :horizontal and/or :vertical](https://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) if you want to only change horizontal/vertical scroll bar.

> :horizontal – The horizontal pseudo-class applies to any scrollbar
>   pieces that have a horizontal orientation.
>
> :vertical – The vertical pseudo-class applies to any scrollbar pieces
>   that have a vertical orientation.